# Maintaining formatting of multiline text when retrieved via Sharepoint web service

Tags: c#, sharepoint, formatting, wsdl

I'm writing a C# app that retrieves data from a SharePoint list via a web service proxy object (created with wsdl.exe). Several of the fields within the lists are multilined plain text. When these fields are displayed using the standard SharePoint web portal the text is formatted correctly (has newlines) but when I get this data using the proxy object all formatting (newlines) have been removed. Does anyone know of to preserves this formatting?

Note: I've also noticed that when retrieving this data using JavaScript the formatting is preserved, so I'm guessing it something to do with the C# proxy object